# svg element does not show up

Tags: css, svg, d3.js

In my code, I append a 'rect' but for some reason it doesn't show up. 
The 'rect' I append shows up in the DOM as:

[image]

Here is my d3.js excerpt when I append it:

```
  var testRect = d3.selectAll(".altIndicator").append("rect")
    .attr("class", "testRect")
    .attr("x", -50)
    .attr("width", 20*x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", -100)
    .attr("height", 425).style("fill", "black").style("opacity", 1);
```

What can be the reason it is not shown ? 
I tried in the console to run this append interactively and it works when I append it anywhere else, so it seems an inheritance issue. However, by setting the style explicitely, it should override the style values inherited from the  element or the CSS.

My complete code is below and the append is line 298-303.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://gist.github.com/EE2dev/d1c86cc47ad2759d955e

Comment: Have you tried different (positive) `x` and `y` values, in case it is offscreen?

Comment: @mgold: Yes, it is on screen. when I hover over the element in the DOM the area it covers is highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's contained in a `g` (the `altIndicator`) that has a 0 opacity.

This is being set here:

```
  d3.selectAll(".altIndicator")
    .each(function (d) { if (selectedItemSet.has(d) && selectedItemSet.get(d).alternativeId != 0) {
      d3.select(this).style("fill", "white")
        .style("opacity", 0.5);
      }
      else {
         d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0);
      }
    });
```

[Code without that line](http://plnkr.co/edit/gJLAoCzv9TOFYZfzCSjS?p=preview).